# Open a second Form with a textbox

Tags: c#

i open about my Button "ProtokollToolStripMenuItemClick" my second Form! The name of the second Form is INPUTBOX! This second Form has two text boxes and one Button! Now i would like to put in my name and my mobile phone number in the two text boxes and close the window with my button. This two entries i would like to put down in my excel application.(But i don´t now how to get the text box entries). How can i do this?

```
public partial class MainForm
{   

    public void ProtokollToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        INPUTBOX _Input = new INPUTBOX();
        _Input.Show();

//Here I want to put in my new code

        //Declaration
        Excel.Application ExcelApplication;
        Excel._Workbook ExcelWorkbook;
        Excel._Worksheet ExcelWorksheet;

        try
        {
            //Start Excel
            ExcelApplication = new Excel.Application();
            ExcelApplication.Visible = true;

            //New Workbook
            ExcelWorkbook = (Excel._Workbook)(ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
            ExcelWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet; 
//et cetera
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open the input box with `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`, to ensure that your code pauses until the window has been closed.
- In your INPUTBOX, create a public property for each of the values you want to return.
- In your button click handler, copy the values from the text boxes to the public properties.
- Afterwards, in the code shown in your question, you can access the values by accessing `_input.NameOfTheNewProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedely you have named your controls `txtName` and `txtPhone` you may access them using the following from the calling form.

```
_Input.txtName.Text
_Input.txtPhone.Text
```